# shotwell bugs with a canon PowerShot A3100 IS

Tags: mount, automount, canon, shotwell, camera

Well, I have a canon PowerShot A3100 IS, and I have some problems while importing videos.
When I try to copy them, it simply doesn't work, and when I try to import them, it starts buging, and the system doesn't respond anymore.

Does anyone know a better software for importing videos/pictures from a camera, or do I need to install a driver ?

Thanks.

Comment: [Shotwell](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/shotwell/) is just photo manager , i don't think it works for videos.

Comment: Do you import them from the camera itself via a USB cable or do you copy them from the SD/MMC (or whatever) card?

Comment: I use the USB cable slashrack.
Sometimes it works ( when the video is not too heavy ) tijybba.

Comment: tijybba, Shotwell will import videos just fine.  This sounds like a hardware issue; a user-mode application on Linux should not be able to bring down the entire computer!

Comment: Sorry I've just corrected that, "the system doesn't respond anymore".

Answer (score 1):

I have a Canon Ixus 115 HS which also produces videos and pictures and I use `gthumb` to import material from the card. You can of course just access the camera and drag and drop material to your home folder, but some photos need to be rotated after import and `gthumb` can do that; however, I uncheck the setting `'rotate photos physically'` on import, as I find it works properly only if I import them and then select the ones to be transformed. (You do this from the menu: tools: rotate physically.) This seems to be the way to get the `EXIF` orientation correct. The 'physical' transformation is important because it is lossless, and if jpgs are modified they can lose quality.

Also, you can't add things back onto the card with `gthumb`; depending on how your camera is recognised (as a digital camera or usb mass storage device), you may need to take the card out and put it in a card reader to do this. However, on the menu of some cameras you can select whether it will be seen as a usb device or camera when connected to a PC.

You mention drivers- actually `gphoto2` is the service that helps digital cameras be recognised and mounted in Unix; it will be running as default as it is used by other photo apps as well. There is a list of supported cameras at [gphoto.org](http://gphoto.org/proj/libgphoto2/support.php).
However, even if yours is not listed it should still work.

If you don't like gthumb, try `Digikam` for KDE, even though it means you'll need to install some of the KDE desktop files.

Comment: The same problem remains with **gthumb** , when I try to import a 700Mo video it stays at 0% and then the system no longer respond.
Do you know where the camera is mounted ?

Comment: Well, I think it's the gphoto2 volume mounter that mounts cameras; you may be able to check gphoto.org for more info. Also, there may be a setting on your camera to alter how it connects to the PC - ie in USB mass storage mode or as a camera. On my other camera, a Nikon D70, there is this option and the USB 'mass storage' setting works well, as the system just sees the camera as a usb flash drive and not actually as a camera. However, if you still can't get your material off of the camera, you could try putting the camera card in a card reader and then transferring the data that way.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about the card reader, I think I gonna search one. Thank you. ( I haven't found how to turn the mass storage mode on .)